# Is there a similar command in python works like `npm install --save`

Tags: python, node.js

I am coming from `nodejs` world. I know python project uses `requirements.txt` to manage the dependencies and their versions. I wonder whether there is an equivalent command like `npm install --save xxx` which installs the dependency `xxx` and also save the dependency on `package.json` file. I know there is a command `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to generate requirements.txt but it will generate it from scratch. What I am looking for is to append extra dependency on that file.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that but if you are using a project-specific virtual environment, it won't be a big issue I guess.  https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-virtual-environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some similar third-party tools like [pipenv](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/) and [poetry](https://poetry.eustace.io/) that allow to do that.
For pipenv saves dependency version inside `Pipfile.lock`

```
$ pipenv install 'django<=2.*'
```

For poetry saves inside `pyproject.toml`

```
$ poetry add django==2.0.5
```